# Can the operating system use ebs transparently?

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, operating-system

I understand we can attach and detach a volume to an instance dynamically.My question is that will the OS allocation these plysicall resource automatically or it should be configured by the user i.e. create a mount point in for file system and explicitly tell the application where the mount point is ?

I use [this](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/quickstart/latest/mongodb/step2a.html) cloud formation to deploy mongodb to aws,the template give users option to specify the volume size to host the database server,just wonder even if I allocate the physical resource,how can the template use it ? How can I know which volume the data reside.When I try to detach one of volume for the instance ,things just break.But I am sure I do not need so many volumes to host data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you need to do that manually as soon as you create a ebs and attach it to a certain instance,you need to follow following steps(On linux systems)

```
- Check if volume is attached and get its name.
   lsblk
- Format the newly attached volume
   mkfs -t ext4 /dev/<volume name>
- Create a mount_point
   mkdir mount_point
- mount the volume to mount point
   mount /dev/<volume_name> mount_point
- Verify the newly attached partition
   df -Ht
```

Can't see your cloud formation template

Comment: Thanks,just figure out the cloud formation allocation the volume and use some user data to mount `/dev/xvdg        25G  3.1G   21G  14% /journal`,what surprise me it that the template allocate 25GB with 250iops for journal,I feel like cheated, the template is https://s3.amazonaws.com/quickstart-reference/mongodb/latest/templates/MongoDB-VPC.template